# Sync WKWebView Cookie to NSHTTPCookieStorage

Tags: ios, cookies, uiwebview, wkwebview, nshttpcookie

`WKWebView` can manage its own cookie in `WKHTTPCookieStorage`, independent with `NSHTTPCookieStorage`. How can I sync cookie from `WKHTTPCookieStore` to `NSHTTPCookieStorage`.

My target is sync the cookies with `WKHTTPCookieStore` and `NSHTTPCookieStorage`.

I try to sync cookie with implement the observer method `WKHTTPCookieStoreObserver`.

```
- (void)cookiesDidChangeInCookieStore:(WKHTTPCookieStore *)cookieStore {
[cookieStore getAllCookies:^(NSArray<NSHTTPCookie *> *array) {
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    NSArray *nsHttpCookies = cookieStorage.cookies;

    //add new Cookie from wkWebView
    [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSHTTPCookie *cookie, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if(![nsHttpCookies containsObject:cookie]){
            [cookieStorage setCookie:cookie];
        }
    }];

    //add old Cookie from wkWebView
    [nsHttpCookies enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSHTTPCookie *cookie, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if(![array containsObject:cookie]){
            [cookieStorage deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
    }];
}];
}
```

It's the right way to sync the cookie from `WKWebView` to `NSHTTPCookieStorage`?

Comment: Hey, did you try to use WKNavigationDelegate instead? Maybe you could use WKNavigationResponse and extract header fields from the urlResponse. In the header fields, you should have a `Cookie` header as a String. Then you can explode it and compare what's missing. It's just an idea

Comment: Unfortunately, at least in iOS 13, the observer method isn't called at all... (https://stackoverflow.com/q/58397343/2778898). So I decided to implement the synchronization manually when initiating a new request.

Answer (score 3):

As Ben answered in a comment you need to extract the cookies from the response header and set them manual in the `HTTPCookieStorage`.

Swift 4:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Swift.Void) {
    guard
        let response = navigationResponse.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
        let url = navigationResponse.response.url
    else {
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
        return
    }

    if let headerFields = response.allHeaderFields as? [String: String] {
        let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: headerFields, for: url)
        cookies.forEach { (cookie) in
             HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)
        }
    }

    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

Objective-C:

```
NSHTTPURLResponse * resp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)[navigationResponse response];
NSDictionary  *diction = [resp allHeaderFields];

NSArray * cookies = [NSHTTPCookie cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:diction forURL:[resp URL]];

for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) {
    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
}

return decisionHandler(YES);
```

Comment: Seems like cookies are not present in the headers anymore. Do you have any other suggestions?